# Usando Count(*) como filtro de tabela

Tags: mysql, sql, select

Bom dia, 
Estou quebrando minha cabeça com o seguinte código:

```
select
ac.cd_agenda as "Código Agenda",
m.nm_pessoa_fisica as "Médico",
esp.ds_especialidade as "Especialidade",
a.ds_complemento as "Agenda",
to_date(ac.dt_agenda, 'dd/mm/yy') "Data",
count(ac.cd_convenio) as "Convênios na Data",
acr.qt_permissao as "Cota",
a.ds_orientacao as Rótulo

from agenda_consulta ac

       join agenda a on a.cd_agenda = ac.cd_agenda
       join setor_atendimento s on s.cd_setor_atendimento = a.cd_setor_agenda
       join pessoa_fisica m on m.cd_pessoa_fisica = a.cd_pessoa_fisica 
       join agrupamento_setor ase on ase.nr_sequencia = s.nr_seq_agrupamento
       join especialidade_medica esp on a.cd_especialidade = esp.cd_especialidade
       join agenda_consulta_regra acr on acr.cd_agenda = ac.cd_agenda

where ac.cd_convenio = '55'
and acr.cd_convenio = '55'
and ac.dt_agenda > sysdate
and acr.ie_periodo = 'D'

group by ac.cd_agenda,
m.nm_pessoa_fisica, 
esp.ds_especialidade,
a.ds_complemento,
to_date(ac.dt_agenda, 'dd/mm/yy'),
a.ds_orientacao,
acr.qt_permissao

having count(ac.cd_convenio) < acr.qt_permissao

order by ac.cd_agenda
```

A tabela atual me retorna todas as datas onde a quantidade de convênios é <= ao valor de cota deste convênio.
Porém eu preciso que a tabela me retorne destas datas **apenas** os dias em qual o critério

`ac.ie_status_agenda = 'L'`

seja atingido.

O problema é, pra fazer a contagem de quantos pacientes temos pelo convênio eu tive que incluir o filtro

`ac.cd_convenio = '55'`

e ie_status_agenda = 'L' tem sempre o valor de cd_convenio nulo.

Fico à disposição pra demais esclarecimentos, minha primeira vez postando aqui, não sei muito bem se me fiz claro.

Agradeço qualquer sugestão!

Comment: Olá bem vindo, aproveita para dar uma vista de olhos no [código de conduta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/conduct).

Comment: Aproveita também para melhorar a tua pergunta, coloca o exemplo de output atual e o esperado. Podes utilizar o [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com) para criares um seed exemplo de dados e fica mais fácil ajudar-te na tua dificuldade.

Comment: Qual é o gerenciador de banco de dados: MySQL ou SQL Server?  No SQL Server não existe a função to_date()

Comment: Como você não deseja considerar todos os registros mas apenas os registros anteriores creio que você precise utilizar uma CTE (Common Table Expressions) em um WITH.

Comment: @JoséDiz é MySQL.

Comment: @ErnestoCasanova Vou tentar, não sou muito familizarado com esse site, mas se eu conseguir colocar lá eu posto aqui pra vocês verem. Obrigado!

Comment: "  incluir o filtro ac.cd_convenio = '55' e ie_status_agenda = 'L' tem sempre o valor de cd_convenio nulo. " ou não entendi ou você tem uma incompatibilidade de testes.